# how to make a beautiful currency display in python?

Tags: python

I have the code:

`money = 3467898542`

`print(money)`

I want the value to be output with dots, example: 3.467.898.542
How do I do this?

I searched the internet, but I didn't find anything. Please help me or give me a link to the answer if there is one

Comment: Notice that with `float`ing numbers you will have conflicts with `.` as a separator of thousands and decimal part: `1542.234` -> `1.542.234`.  Choose a new symbol for the decimal part and maybe check-type solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
money = 3467898542
print(f"{money:_}".replace("_", "."))
```

Prints:

```
3.467.898.542
```

Answer (score 1):

```
money = 3467898542
formatted_money = format(money, ',').replace(',', '.')
print(formatted_money)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make translation table with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.maketrans) which will manage the symbols for separating thousands and decimal part. Then `str.translate` to apply the substitution.

Notice the you can declare the translation table as a global variable which is more suitable when you have repeated usage.

```
money_formatted = f"{money:_}".translate(str.maketrans({'_': '.', '.': ','}))
print(money, '->', money_formatted)
#1542.234 -> 1.542,234
```

Comment: It is an extension of Andrej Kesely's answer